# Change view without navigating?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, navigation, windows-phone

I am creating an App in which I have a menu that will display on every page. The menu contains navigation to another page, so I can avoid repeating the same code on every page and in XAML. How can I change the view of a page without navigating to another page?

Comment: another, more simple, option is to create custom user control.

Comment: Will you Give me a link or Tell me How i can do that

Comment: ok,i think this is exactly what you need http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/why-and-how-to-create-a-user-control-in-windows-phone

Comment: Is there one question(problem) or two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xaml allows you to handle Frames, which are quite like html's iframes :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/cc838245(v=vs.95).aspx

some frameworks, like caliburn micro, ease the use of such frames.

Comment: This is What i am asking Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hey Dont know exactly What you want,but according to my understanding you can use Pivot and Panorama control.
This is the best control according to your requirement.
Here is the sample code and description.
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/PanoramaPivot-Sample-332a7e06

Comment: panorama and pivot is not according to my design